# Problema em botão com Javascript

Tags: javascript

Há algum tempo fiz [esta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/63471/bot%C3%A3o-avan%C3%A7ar-voltar-em-um-slide) pergunta, para saber como poderia adicionar um botão para voltar e passar um slide. Enfim, consegui fazer os botões, porém agora estou tendo um problema. Ao clicar nos botões pela primeira vez, em prev ele passa o slide, mas fica com o conteúdo de um subscrevendo o outro, e em next ele só passa se clicar duas vezes. O que pode estar errado?

*Ps: O erro só acontece no primeiro clique assim que a página carrega, sendo em next ou prev, depois funciona normalmente.*

```js
function simpleSlider(type){
         var sliderActive = $("#slider .sliderActive");
          if(type == 'prev') {
           var sliderPrev   = sliderActive.prev().length ? sliderActive.prev() : $("#slider li:last");
                     sliderPrev.addClass('sliderActive').fadeIn();
          } else {
                     var sliderNext   = sliderActive.next().length ? sliderActive.next() : $("#slider li:first");
                     sliderNext.addClass('sliderActive').fadeIn();
                 }
                 sliderActive.removeClass('sliderActive').fadeOut();
            }
        $(function(){
            $("#slider li:first").fadeIn();
            
        });
```

```css
#slider {
    list-style:none;
    width:800px;
    height:700px;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:0;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
#slider li {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 0;
    display:none;
}
#slider li.sliderActive {
    z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="buttons">
 <a href="javascript:simpleSlider('prev')"><span>prev</span></a>
 <a href="javascript:simpleSlider('next')"><span>next</span></a>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="slider">
    <li><div class="box_inside box_crm">
        <span class="icon_serv_crm"></span>
        <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h3>
        <p class="principal"><strong>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</strong></p>
        <p>Maecenas sagittis, lorem non imperdiet faucibus, neque turpis porta velit, ultrices ullamcorper elit tellus in nisl. Maecenas enim felis, sollicitudin convallis tristique at, ultrices quis mauris. Pellentesque et fringilla nunc. Phasellus magna metus, placerat eget tincidunt non, dictum non nisi. </p>    
        <div class="content_btn center" style="width:100%">
            <a href="#" class="btn">Saiba mais</a>        
        </div>
    </div></li>
    <li><div class="box_inside box_landing">
        <span class="icon_serv_land"></span>
        <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h3>
        <p class="principal"><strong>t facilisis et sapien a auctor. Cras in iaculis eros, ac tincidunt mi. Aenean auctor ultricies dolor, sed dictum lectus iaculis sed. Nullam lobortis</strong></p>
        <p>t facilisis et sapien a auctor. Cras in iaculis eros, ac tincidunt mi. Aenean auctor ultricies dolor, sed dictum lectus iaculis sed. Nullam lobortis</p>    
        <div class="content_btn center" style="width:100%">
            <a href="http://localhost/" class="btn">Saiba mais</a>        
        </div>
    </div></li>
</ul>
```

**O erro pode ser reproduzido no snippet acima.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é que, ao carregar a página, nenhum elemento da lista está com a classe `sliderActive` e, como a lógica do slider funciona através desta classe, ocorre este problema na primeira vez, porque nas demais ele adiciona a classe no novo elemento ativo.

Apenas adicionei aquela classe no primeiro `li`.

```js
function simpleSlider(type){
         var sliderActive = $("#slider .sliderActive");
          if(type == 'prev') {
           var sliderPrev   = sliderActive.prev().length ? sliderActive.prev() : $("#slider li:last");
                     sliderPrev.addClass('sliderActive').fadeIn();
          } else {
                     var sliderNext   = sliderActive.next().length ? sliderActive.next() : $("#slider li:first");
                     sliderNext.addClass('sliderActive').fadeIn();
                 }
                 sliderActive.removeClass('sliderActive').fadeOut();
            }
        $(function(){
            $("#slider li:first").fadeIn();
            
        });
```

```css
#slider {
    list-style:none;
    width:800px;
    height:700px;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:0;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
#slider li {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 0;
    display:none;
}
#slider li.sliderActive {
    z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="buttons">
 <a href="javascript:simpleSlider('prev')"><span>prev</span></a>
 <a href="javascript:simpleSlider('next')"><span>next</span></a>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="slider">
    <li class="sliderActive"><div class="box_inside box_crm">
        <span class="icon_serv_crm"></span>
        <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h3>
        <p class="principal"><strong>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</strong></p>
        <p>Maecenas sagittis, lorem non imperdiet faucibus, neque turpis porta velit, ultrices ullamcorper elit tellus in nisl. Maecenas enim felis, sollicitudin convallis tristique at, ultrices quis mauris. Pellentesque et fringilla nunc. Phasellus magna metus, placerat eget tincidunt non, dictum non nisi. </p>    
        <div class="content_btn center" style="width:100%">
            <a href="#" class="btn">Saiba mais</a>        
        </div>
    </div></li>
    <li><div class="box_inside box_landing">
        <span class="icon_serv_land"></span>
        <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h3>
        <p class="principal"><strong>t facilisis et sapien a auctor. Cras in iaculis eros, ac tincidunt mi. Aenean auctor ultricies dolor, sed dictum lectus iaculis sed. Nullam lobortis</strong></p>
        <p>t facilisis et sapien a auctor. Cras in iaculis eros, ac tincidunt mi. Aenean auctor ultricies dolor, sed dictum lectus iaculis sed. Nullam lobortis</p>    
        <div class="content_btn center" style="width:100%">
            <a href="http://localhost/" class="btn">Saiba mais</a>        
        </div>
    </div></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Perfeito, funcionou! Não havia notado isso. Muito obrigado @Lucas!